# Django cms - custom page (type)

Tags: python, django, django-cms

i try to generate a django cms application with different page types.

Currently i do that like that:

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('content.html', 'Base'),
    ('category.html', 'Category'),
)
```

So i can create different pages for different product categories.

But i would like to build a custom "renderer" or something like that, where i can do some db calls to retrieve some products. (Depending on some custom page attributes)

Currently i set the custom page attributes by PageExtension from django cms.

Can you give me a hint to that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you are looking for how to make custom views in django.

You can check the oficial documentation on this subject here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/

Comment: I think on that too, but i don't know how to use that with a django-cms page